# Choosing right "bucket" for Bucket Sort

Tags: java, insertion

I'm preforming a Bucket sort, I'm accepting an `int` parameter and I wanted to insert it into a Node "bucket" that holds up to 8 `ints`. Once the `int` is in the array in the Node, I will perform an ordered search so that they are in ascending order. My question is how do I choose the right Node "bucket" to insert these `int` values? I think generally that for a Bucket sort, you are given the number of buckets, but I'm not sure what to do in my case.

I was thinking something along the lines of: (to see if my Bucket is full)

```
if(array[max] != 0)
{
  array[size] = element;
  size++;
} 
else
{
  int[] newArray = new int[max];
  newArray[newSize] = element;
  newSize;

}
```

But then I'm going to have to if else statements for up to 5000 inserted values. Any idea how to choose the right "bucket"?

Comment: What do you mean with the *right bucket*; depending on the radix and the exponent you are currently evaluating, there is only one such bucket.

Answer (score 1):

In a bucket sort, each bucket is allocated a subrange of the possible key values, often based on the value of the high order bits of the key. Each input element is placed in the bucket for the subrange in which it falls. Each of the buckets is individually sorted, and then concatenated to get the sorted result. See [Bucket Sort](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BucketSort.html) for a visualization.

Each bucket needs to be designed to contain the maximum possible number of elements that could map to it. There is nothing you can do to complete the sort if a bucket is "full". If you have 1000 buckets and each bucket is to contain at most 8 elements, your input keys have to be limited to an 8000 element subrange of the integers.

You should have a simple arithmetic expression based on the key value that yields the bucket number for that key. For example, if sorting elements from [0,7999] using 1000 buckets, you could divide the key by 8 and round down to an integer. Often, the number of buckets is a power of two and the bucket number for a key is just the appropriate number of high order bits from the key.